# modx list all contents published between given date range

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

I am using modx advsearch snippet to list search results.

```
[[!AdvSearch?
&extractLength=`220`
&queryHook=`ArticleSearchQHook`
&extractEllipsis=`.`
&contexts=`web,tech,data,main`
&tpl=`articleSearchResult`
&perPage=`10`
&minChars=`2`
&withTVs=`docGroup,post_category,post_subcategory,category`
&fields=`pagetitle,longtitle,description,introtext,content,publishedon`]]
```

i want to show results which are published between given date range. So i am using 2 text boxes with datepicker plugin. I am able to see the selected dates in URl like below

```
pubfromdate=2012-11-01&pubtodate=2012-12-18&search=tech&sub=Search
```

How can i filter result based on date range ?

There is another issue, publishedon column stores date in "timestamp" format as you know and my textfields accepts "DMY" format, but thats not a big deal i think, i can handle that issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this hook in `queryHook`

```
<?php

$andConditions = array();

if (!empty($_REQUEST['pubfromdate']) && $pubfromdate = strtotime($_REQUEST['pubfromdate'])) {
    $andConditions['modResource.publishedon:>'] = "{$pubfromdate}:numeric";
}

if (!empty($_REQUEST['pubtodate']) && $pubtodate = strtotime($_REQUEST['pubtodate'])) {
    $andConditions['modResource.publishedon:<'] = "{$pubtodate}:numeric";
}

if (!empty($andConditions)) {
    $qhDeclaration = array(
        'qhVersion' => '1.2',
        'andConditions' => $andConditions
    );
    $hook->setQueryHook($qhDeclaration);
}

return true;
```

Comment: Vasis, your solution worked perfect. Once more you saved me. Thanks a ton. :) I have spend all the day to solve this, but in wrong direction.

Comment: Is there anyway i can see query running behind this ? So i can be more clear how this thing works ??

Comment: See examples of `queryHook` in documentation - http://www.revo.wangba.fr/advsearch-documentation.html maybe this help.

Comment: I have been reading this for all the day, i saw example which was best suited my requirements (its on page 3 'andCondition') There i saw 'tv.articleMark:>=' => 'minf,request,none’, So i thought its something related to TV's and i wasted my day reading TV. (this is what i said "wrong direction" in my previous comment). I have ordered MODx Official guide, Hopefully it will make my modx concepts little better.